# Trouble getting to PayPal "Buy Now" buttons to work on a single page in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, paypal

I confess I am a noob to asp.net and web forms. I'm having an issue incorporating a few PayPal "Buy Now" buttons on a single page.  Basically, the problem is no matter which "Buy Now" button is clicked, the user is taken to PayPal to buy the product represented by the last button on the page.

The code for my first button is something like this...

```
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="ABC123">
<asp:ImageButton runat="server" id="PPImageButton1" PostBackUrl="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" ImageUrl="https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynow_SM.gif"/>
```

My second button is similar to...

```
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="ABC456">
<asp:ImageButton runat="server" id="PPImageButton2" PostBackUrl="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" ImageUrl="https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynow_SM.gif"/>
```

How can I make the first button send value ABC123 to the PayPal service instead of ABC456?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The POST content of a button is every input in the FORM tag that surrounds the submit button. So to have each button submit a separate set of hidden fields you need to wrap the button and the desired hidden fields in a separate form:

```
<form ... >
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="ABC123">
<asp:ImageButton runat="server" id="PPImageButton1" PostBackUrl="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" ImageUrl="https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynow_SM.gif"/>
</form>

<form ... >
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="ABC456">
<asp:ImageButton runat="server" id="PPImageButton1" PostBackUrl="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" ImageUrl="https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynow_SM.gif"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I basically screwed up in my explanation in that I didn't provide adequate detail.  It is a SharePoint site and when I tried to add a second Form tag (to create the 1st button, I received an error stating nested forms were not supported in ASP.NET.  So, I pulled the <form> out and the first button worked OK.  Then when I added the 2nd button, I found the issue.

Comment: <form>
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="ABC12">
asp:ImageButton runat="server" id="PPImageButton1" PostBackUrl="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" ImageUrl="https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynow_SM.gif"/>
</form>
<form>
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="ABC34">
<asp:ImageButton runat="server" id="PPImageButton2" PostBackUrl="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" ImageUrl="https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynow_SM.gif"/>
</form>

Comment: My last comment is the current code which does not work.  The first button appears to fucntion properly while the second button only refreshes the page.

Comment: Remus, you comments helped.  I recieved some bad advice before posting here.  I added the approprite switches to the <form> line and it appears to be working fine now.  Thank you for setting me on the proper course.

Answer (score 1):

My noob solution for this was to cut each of the buy-it-now buttons and its associated fields out of the aspx page, and put each set in a separate html page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>first button</title>
</head>

<body>
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="paypal">
<input type="hidden" value="_s-xclick" name="cmd" /> <input type="hidden" value="???????" name="hosted_button_id" /> 
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td><input type="hidden" value="Member name" name="on0" />Member name</td>

<td><input maxlength="60" size="30" name="os0" /></td></tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="hidden" value="Membership No. (if known)" name="on1" />Membership No. (if known)</td>
<td><input maxlength="60" size="6" name="os1" /></td></tr></tbody></table>
<input type="image" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online." src="https://www.paypal.com/en_GB/i/btn/btn_cart_LG.gif"  name="submit" /> <img height="1" alt="" src="https://www.paypal.com/en_GB/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" border="0"/> </form>

</body>
</html>
```

In the place in the aspx page where you removed the button and other fields, insert an iframe which points to the html page like this:

```
<iframe width="600" height="" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="mybuttonpage1.htm"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it to work by removing all the other button containers from the DOM in jQuery. Add a class to your container, and add a CssClass to the ImageButton, "PayPalImageButtons"

```
<div>
    Buy This First Product Below
</div>
<div class="ManualPurchase PayPalButtons">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick" />
    <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="ABC123" />
    <asp:ImageButton CssClass="PayPalImageButtons" runat="server" id="PPImageButton1" PostBackUrl="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" ImageUrl="https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynow_SM.gif" />
</div>

<div>
    Buy This Second Product Below
</div>
<div class="ManualPurchase PayPalButtons">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick" />
    <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="ABC456" />
    <asp:ImageButton CssClass="PayPalImageButtons" runat="server" id="PPImageButton1" PostBackUrl="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" ImageUrl="https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynow_SM.gif" />
</div>
```

and the jQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function pageLoad() {
        $(".PayPalImageButtons").click(function (e) {
            $(this).parent().addClass("keep");
            $(".PayPalButtons").not(".keep").remove();
        });
    }
</script>
```

My next step is dealing with the removed elements height and maybe a Please Wait dialog while the PayPal page is loaded